# Get list of Windows 8.1 processes using Python

Tags: python, python-2.7, subprocess, wmi, pid

I want to get the list of processes in memory including the name and the PID in Windows 8.1.

Here's my code:

```
import subprocess
import os

cmd = "WMIC PROCESS get Caption,ProcessId"
proc = subprocess.Popen(cmd, shell=True, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
for line in proc.stdout:
  # Additional logic here
```

The loop never runs.  This code worked in an earlier version of Windows 8.  Is there a different approach someone can recommend?

Comment: Does the actual command line still work?

Comment: Yes it does.  I can run "WMIC PROCESS get Caption,ProcessId" in the command line (cmd), and it gives me exactly what I want.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of the cumbersome `subprocess`, you can use the fabolous, cross-platform [psutil](https://pypi.org/project/psutil/#functions) library.

Using the general purpose `psutil.process_iter()` will allow you to do pretty much anything you'd like with the `Process` objects it returns (get name, pid, filter the ones you're interested in, etc.)

E.g.

```
for proc in psutil.process_iter():
    print proc.pid, proc.name
```

Comment: This is a great solution, so I am marking it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Shx2, thank you for your response.  While your solution is better for multiplatform support, here's the solution I went with since I'm only running Windows 8.1.

```
 from win32com.client import GetObject

 Wmi = GetObject('winmgmts:')
 processes = Wmi.InstancesOf('Win32_Process')

 # Get the Explorer process
 explorer = Wmi.ExecQuery('select * from Win32_Process where Name="explorer.exe"')

 # Grab its Pid
 processId = explorer[0].Properties_('ProcessId').Value
```